# Construction of the Octonions

Tags: octonions

I get how to construct number systems: $\Bbb{N,~Z,~Q,~R,~C}$. But what about the hypercomplex? How do we go from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb H$ and $\Bbb O$?

I've also heard it stated that the octonions are the "center" of mathematics. If that's true, then what would be a good way to explain or depict that graphically?

---

I took the liberty of adding the crucial part of the [interview within the linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0QtZmLC14U&feature=youtu.be) in the question body to make it more easy to understand the part where the OP said that he heard "the octonions are the 'center' of mathematics".

> *Eric Weinstein:*
>
> *"If I were running the [NSF](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Science_Foundation) I would say why are we not putting money into there four very strange objects called [$F4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F4_(mathematics)), [$E6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics)), [$E7$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E7_(mathematics)) and [$E8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)) to try to figure out what they are telling us. We know, that they are **at the center of mathematics**"* [emphasis by me]

Comment: I never heard that Octonions are the "center" of mathematics in any context. However, regarding the construction: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) and then [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction).

Comment: @mrtaurho https://youtu.be/Q0QtZmLC14U

Comment: It seems to arise when one constructs exceptional simple Lie groups, such as in https://people.ucsc.edu/~weissman/WhatIsG2.pdf ... But I dare not say more.

Comment: @user40358 I have watched the whole interview now (thanks for the link!) but either I missed the point where he actually states that *'octonions are the "center" of mathematics'* or it was not there. The only connection I can see at all between this interview and octonions is via Lie Groups and Lie Algebras as he is talking about the [$E_8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)), which has a close connection to Lie Algebras too. As I am far from being an expert in this field I can not evaluate the importance of this - from my point of view *loose* - relation between them.

Comment: @mrtaurho He says it at about 2:40.

Comment: @user40358 Well, to be precise he says "we know that they are (the groups he named before) *at the center of mathematics*". I added the crucial part of the interview to your question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction